# Textbox value onclick onblur issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBOX" 
        runat="server"              
        CssClass="text"
        Height="32px" 
        Width="360px"  
        TextMode=MultiLine         
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        AcceptsReturn="True"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        onclick="if(this.value='<%=_data.Obsprevia.ToString()%>'){this.value=''}"             
        onblur="if(this.value=''){this.value='<%=TxtObservaciones.Text.ToString()%>'}">

     </asp:TextBox>
```

That's my code.

Default TxtBOX.Text comes from code behind (_data_obsprevia). What I want to achieve is, a clean up of that default text once the user clicks on the textbox. And if the txbox lose focus while the user didn't write anything, get back that default text.

I can't achieve that, and if the user DID write something, and lose-gain focus again, the textbox gets empty again.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Fixed the == inside the IFs, Now it looks like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBOX" 
        runat="server"              
        CssClass="text"
        Height="32px" 
        Width="360px"  
        TextMode=MultiLine         
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        AcceptsReturn="True"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        onclick="if(this.value=='<%=_data.Obsprevia.ToString()%>'){this.value=''}"             
        onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='<%=TxtObservaciones.Text.ToString()%>'}">

     </asp:TextBox>
```

But when I first click on it, it's not cleaning the deafult data. And if I erase it, and go losing focus it shows `<%=TxtObservaciones.Text.ToString()%>` 
Not the value held inside of it.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, a build onto insertusernamehere's suggestion..

```
onclick="if(this.value=='<%=_data.Obsprevia.ToString()%>'){this.value=''}"             
onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=document.getElementById('<%= TxtObservaciones.ClientID %>').value}"
```

This gets what is set in the textbox from javascript, in case it is changed in the browser.

You also might need to break the code out into functions

```
     function TxtBOX_OnClick() {
         var TxtBOX = document.getElementById("<%= TxtBOX.ClientID %>");
         if (TxtBOX.value == "<%=_data.Obsprevia.ToString()%>") {
             TxtBOX.value = '';
         }
     }
     function TxtBOX_OnBlur() {
         var TxtBOX = document.getElementById("<%= TxtBOX.ClientID %>");
         if (TxtBOX.value == '') {
             TxtBOX.value = document.getElementById("<%= TxtObservaciones.ClientID %>").value;
         }
     }
```

and

```
onclick="TxtBOX_OnClick();"             
onblur="TxtBOX_OnBlur();"
```

Comment: Give that a try, it needed to replace this with finding the element. I had it working on a text page (with the OnClick using a basic string to test)

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
if (this.value == '') {}
```

As `==` compares values and `=` asigns a value.

Comment: I don't know ASP, maybe there's a problem with the values `<%=_data.Obsprevia.ToString()%>` and `<%=TxtObservaciones.Text.ToString()%>`?

Comment: Oh sorry, recognition will definetely go to answerers :). Thanks, will keep trying

Comment: Forget what I've said in the comment - corrected it already - as you've updated your question quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<input type="text" value="Search..." onclick="if(this.value=='Search...'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Search...'}">
```

I'm not familiar with ASP, but hopefully this can help :)